# How to declare directives in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

When i tried using directives,it says error

```
Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; providers: typeof HeaderClass[]; directives: typeof Moda...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
```

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Here is my code,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/common/common.component.html',
  providers: [HeaderClass],
  directives: [ModalComponent]
})
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Well, just believe what the error message says. There is no directives attribute. Remove it. directives and components must be added to the declarations of their NgModule. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declarations

Comment: Hi Nizet but how can i pass values through a directive meta tag i.e like this <modal   [value]=?></modal>

Comment: Using component inputs. You really need to read the documentation. Or read a good book about angular. My company sells one, for a minimum of 5 euros: https://books.ninja-squad.com/angular.

Answer (score 1):

In the older version Angular2 , like beta , that was how you would define a directive.

But after rc, you don't do that anymore and you declare that directive in the modules.

```
@NgModule({

   declarations:[ModalComponent]

})
```